# how to migrate my huge website from hosting company to another one?

Tags: ssh, hosting, server, transfer

i want to know what is the fastest way to migrate my site (larger than 70GB) (approx 700MB database) from one server to another i think ftp in this case is a joke what hosting companies uses in this case since i saw many scenarios where big websites transferred in 2 hours or 5 hours at most what did they used.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the preferable solution (from my own experience) would be if:

1. You have quick physical access to both your old and your new server.
2. The hosting companies allows you to use persistance carriers (128 GB
   USB Stick, 128 GB SSD, etc.)
   Then you go to your old hosting provider, copy your (backed up) site from the old server to the USB Stick (or SSD), you go to your new hosting provider and then copy the backed up site to the new server.
   You'll have to transfer your site twice, but the transfer speed would be sufficient enough, so you can quickly set up your site on the new server.

If you can do anything physically and the remote access is the only option you have, then you'll probably need to ensure a temporary direct connection between the two servers can be established so you can transfer your backed up site directly to the new server (FTP connections aren't necessarily slow, they could also allow big traffic throughputs).

Another solution would be to archive and compress your site, then back it up somewhere locally to you, upload it to the new server and finally uncompress it on that new server (so you'll have to transfer the site twice).

Comment: no this is not the case .. i asked my local hosting company (reseller) to give me a compressed copy of my site they answered me they don't have a copy of my site because it's semi impossible to download my huge site locally but all they asked for is my new hosting cpanel credential then after 2 hours they inform me your site transferred successfully. this is all what i need to know what is the trick here the hidden operation .. i am suspicious about ssh (secure shell protocol) .. i think it's server to server process no ftp client needed.

Comment: @user2188424, well, they used some peer-to-peer connection between the old and the new hosting provider. It could also be possible to use SSH Connection, but the transfer speed does not depend that much on the protocol - FTP and SSH are just communication protocols. It is the connection throughput that is important.